# Updating a variable on each row within a SQL Select statement

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm trying to update a column based on the most recent code that was not equal to 1000, if there are duplicate 1000 codes, they should all change to the most recent code not equal to 1000.

In SQL Server 2012 I have tried lag statements, creating a row ID and joining to same table -1 row which both work, but the problem is duplicates. There can be many 1000 codes in a row, but I need to retain the timestamps and change them all to the most recent code not equal to 1000

```
SELECT
    EqmtID
    ,Reason
    ,StartTime

FROM cyclesRID
```

Produces:

```
EqmtID                 Reason  StartTime
1903010010000030808    1007    23759
1903010010000030808    1005    24965
1903010010000030808    1000    25382
1903010010000030808    1000    26078
1903010010000030808    1000    27180
1903010010000030808    1000    27761
1903010010000025572    1004    8601
```

I need to edit the select statement to produce:

```
EqmtID                 Reason  StartTime
1903010010000030808    1007    23759
1903010010000030808    1005    24965
1903010010000030808    1005    25382
1903010010000030808    1005    26078
1903010010000030808    1005    27180
1903010010000030808    1005    27761
1903010010000025572    1004    8601
```

Also partitioned by EqmtID, if there is a 1000 code as the first row for a  partition, then it should change to 1001.

If I was doing this in Python I would use a variable that only updates if not equal to 1000. Can something similar be done in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use a correlated subquery to find the nearest non `1000` `Reason` code to be used in updating:

```
UPDATE c1
SET Reason = (SELECT TOP 1 Reason FROM cyclesRID c2
              WHERE c2.EqmtID = c2.EqmtID AND
                    Reason <> 1000 AND c2.StartTime < c1.StartTime
              ORDER BY StartTime DESC)
FROM cyclesRID c1
WHERE Reason = 1000;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: You're a master sir, thanks very much. It's always so simple once you see it! Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Have implemented and it's working, I should probably just point out that it should be c1.EqmtID = c2.EqmtID on the third line there.